# Show UITextView.inputView when connected to Bluetooth Keyboard

Tags: iphone, ios

I have a application where i need to provide the support for bluetooth keyboard as well as normal keyboard for UITextView.

I have a inputView designed for the UITextView. It works properly and shows images when the bluetooth keyboard is not connected. How to show UITextView.inputView when connected to bluetooth keyboard ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And you have tried it with the BT keyboard?

Comment: Did you try `-[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder]`

Comment: Undo : Yeah i am trying with BT keyboard